# Cut substring between character

Tags: oracle

I want to select the 3 numbers between ":". I don't know the length of this strings and the positions of the ":". I have as an example:

```
SELECT 'Espacio Asignado:358898204672: Espacio Usado:355976458989: Espacio Reclamable:2921745683:' FROM DUAL;
```

I think that with `regexp`, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute:

```
select total
from (SELECT regexp_substr('Espacio Asignado:358898204672: Espacio Usado:355976458989: Espacio Reclamable:2921745683:','[^:]+', 1, level) total
      FROM DUAL
      connect by regexp_substr('Espacio Asignado:358898204672: Espacio Usado:355976458989: Espacio Reclamable:2921745683:','[^:]+', 1, level) is not null)
where   REGEXP_LIKE(total, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
/
```

You get all the numeric values in the string.